# How to install all the software in same folder in fedora

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have installed fedora. I install software by yum in command line. But i have found that not all software installs in same folder. They installed in different folder. How can i will able install them into same folder.

Comment: You need to describe the actual problem you're having, not just how you propose to solve it. Otherwise, you get an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/167586) that cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2):

Except for the very simplest software, Linux software packages typically contain any number of files that will be installed in standard, recognized locations in the file system. Executable applications intended for general use by ordinary users are often in the /usr/bin directory, while executable applications intended for use by the system itself and/or the root user (adminstrator) are typically installed into /bin or /sbin or /usr/sbin, etc.

Meanwhile, libraries that provide needed support are found in directories like /lib, /usr/lib, etc.

Your Linux system knows where these files are located; manually moving them can break a system and should be avoided.